# I'm trying to deploy a Laravel app with fly.io, but i constantly get an error that it's not getting resolved by myself

Tags: laravel, deployment, build, fly

I'm trying to deploy a Laravel app with fly.io, but i constantly get this error:

> *ERROR [base 3/4] RUN composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev   8.2s

> Error: failed to fetch an image or build from source: error building: failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev     && mkdir -p storage/logs     && php artisan optimize:clear     && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html     && sed -i 's/protected $proxies/protected $proxies = "*"/g' app/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php     && echo "MAILTO=""\n* * * * * www-data /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run" > /etc/cron.d/laravel     && cp .fly/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint     && chmod +x /entrypoint]: exit code: 1

> - 

But i cannot understand why, 'cause single commands work by themselves.
did anyone get the same issue?

i tried with `fly launch` as the docs say, but it stop after a while.

down there it's my composer.json:

```
 {
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "google/cloud-vision": "^1.6",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/fortify": "^1.17",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.8",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
        "laravel/scout": "^10.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
        "livewire/livewire": "^2.12",
        "outhebox/blade-flags": "^1.2",
        "spatie/image": "^2.2",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^5.10",
        "teamtnt/laravel-scout-tntsearch-driver": "^12.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.8",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.18",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.1",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

and this is my dockerfile:

```
`# syntax = docker/dockerfile:experimental

# Default to PHP 8.2, but we attempt to match
# the PHP version from the user (wherever `flyctl launch` is run)
# Valid version values are PHP 7.4+
ARG PHP_VERSION=8.2
ARG NODE_VERSION=18
FROM fideloper/fly-laravel:${PHP_VERSION} as base

# PHP_VERSION needs to be repeated here
# See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact
ARG PHP_VERSION

LABEL fly_launch_runtime="laravel"

# copy application code, skipping files based on .dockerignore
COPY . /var/www/html

RUN composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev \
    && mkdir -p storage/logs \
    && php artisan optimize:clear \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html \
    && sed -i 's/protected \$proxies/protected \$proxies = "*"/g' app/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php \
    && echo "MAILTO=\"\"\n* * * * * www-data /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run" > /etc/cron.d/laravel \
    && cp .fly/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint \
    && chmod +x /entrypoint

# If we're using Octane...
RUN if grep -Fq "laravel/octane" /var/www/html/composer.json; then \
        rm -rf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/fpm.conf; \
        if grep -Fq "spiral/roadrunner" /var/www/html/composer.json; then \
            mv /etc/supervisor/octane-rr.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/octane-rr.conf; \
            if [ -f ./vendor/bin/rr ]; then ./vendor/bin/rr get-binary; fi; \
            rm -f .rr.yaml; \
        else \
            mv .fly/octane-swoole /etc/services.d/octane; \
            mv /etc/supervisor/octane-swoole.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/octane-swoole.conf; \
        fi; \
        rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default; \
        ln -sf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default-octane /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default; \
    fi

# Multi-stage build: Build static assets
# This allows us to not include Node within the final container
FROM node:${NODE_VERSION} as node_modules_go_brrr

RUN mkdir /app

RUN mkdir -p  /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
COPY --from=base /var/www/html/vendor /app/vendor

# Use yarn or npm depending on what type of
# lock file we might find. Defaults to
# NPM if no lock file is found.
# Note: We run "production" for Mix and "build" for Vite
RUN if [ -f "vite.config.js" ]; then \
        ASSET_CMD="build"; \
    else \
        ASSET_CMD="production"; \
    fi; \
    if [ -f "yarn.lock" ]; then \
        yarn install --frozen-lockfile; \
        yarn $ASSET_CMD; \
    elif [ -f "pnpm-lock.yaml" ]; then \
        corepack enable && corepack prepare pnpm@latest-7 --activate; \
        pnpm install --frozen-lockfile; \
        pnpm run $ASSET_CMD; \
    elif [ -f "package-lock.json" ]; then \
        npm ci --no-audit; \
        npm run $ASSET_CMD; \
    else \
        npm install; \
        npm run $ASSET_CMD; \
    fi;

# From our base container created above, we
# create our final image, adding in static
# assets that we generated above
FROM base

# Packages like Laravel Nova may have added assets to the public directory
# or maybe some custom assets were added manually! Either way, we merge
# in the assets we generated above rather than overwrite them
COPY --from=node_modules_go_brrr /app/public /var/www/html/public-npm
RUN rsync -ar /var/www/html/public-npm/ /var/www/html/public/ \
    && rm -rf /var/www/html/public-npm \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/public

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint"]
```

Comment: Is this a problem related to Composer? if not, please remove the tag. Also, why not use **individual**  commands? This would help to see which one throws the error

Comment: I don't think it's related to it, tag removed.
IWhat do you mean with individual? fly deploy gives me same errors and composer install or update work fine.

Comment: Individual commands would have one `RUN` per command, not a long line of concatenated commands. Replace `&&` by `RUN` for this